# Alternative to Weight Painting?

Tags: rigging

I'm used to skin rigging in 3DS Max, is there a way to select vertices and just add weights to them according to what bone you have selected? Like a weight table?

I'm also having this annoying issue where the ring isn't 100% following the piece of armor even though it's fully weighted on the left shoulder bone and not the right shoulder bone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Switch to Edit mode, select the vertices you want then in the Object Data panel, select the vertex groups you want, set the Weight and click on Assign?

Comment: @moonboots I think I did it but, it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

That. For your second question, if the armor and ring are in the same mesh you can select all the verts in the ring (edit mode), select one vert in the armor, then copy the bone weights from the active vert in the armor to the rest of them in the ring. Ring verts will all have the same weight, so the ring won't warp, and they'll stick with the armor vert you used as your template. Copy the weights with the tools panel ("N"), "Item" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to *Edit* mode, select the vertices you want then in the *Object Data* panel, select the vertex groups you want, set the *Weight* and click on *Assign*.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you can assign weights manually without using painting. Both in edit mode.

From left to right: Vertex Weights panel (similar to the weights table in 3DS) and Vertex Groups panel:
[image: weights editing]

In the Properties Editor, Mesh tab, Vertex Groups panel, you can see the list of all your vertex groups. There you can choose a group and assign it to a vertex with a specific weight.

In the viewport sidebar (bring it by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> in the viewport), Item tab, Vertex Weights panel, you can see a list of all assigned weights for your selection. There you can manually set the weights, normalize them (which is very important to avoid unwanted behaviors, like what you have with your ring). You can also unassign weights, but you can't assign them, and the list displays only the weights already assigned to your selection.

Comment: So now, I still have this habit of adding an "autokey" so when I set weights to some vertices, I would move the animation slider back and forward to see how the one part of the model would move but, seeing that I won't be able to do that while in edit mode?

Comment: You can, just make sure to enable the edit preview on your Armature Deform modifier.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll see what I can do.